# How to limit the axios get request results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, github-api

I am trying use an axios request to fetch data from github api, but for some reason _limit is not returning the limited number of results?

```
await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/freeCodeCamp/repos?_limit=10`)
            .then(
                (res) => {
                    console.log(res.data);
                    
                }
            )
```

The following http request is working perfectly by limiting the results

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=2

Whereas the following http request is not limiting the data

https://api.github.com/users/freeCodeCamp/repos?_limit=2

What's the difference between the above two requests?

Comment: the server is different, so the code serving the request will be different .. `_limit` isn't some "standard" search parameter that just works anywhere, it has nothing to do with using axios either

Comment: There is no `_limit` parameter in the GitHub API. You can check out **all the parameters** in [the GitHub API documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos).

Comment: @Bravo thanks for that, then how should I limit the number of results for this axios request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_limit` parameter you see in https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com is specific to their [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#paginate) software.

From [the Github REST API documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#list-repositories-for-a-user), you want to use the `per_page` parameter

```js
const { data } = await axios.get("https://api.github.com/users/freeCodeCamp/repos", {
  params: {
    per_page: 10
  }
})
```

My general advice for using any REST API... **always** read the documentation specific to the resource you're consuming.

---

Sorting options for API results are limited to `created`, `updated`, `pushed` and `full_name` (default). If you want to sort by something else, you'll need to do that client-side, eg

```js
data.sort((a, b) => a.stargazers_count - b.stargazers_count);
```

Comment: thanks for that. And how can I sort the results according to the number of stars and forks?

Comment: @chris you cannot do that with the API. The options for `sort` are `created`, `updated`, `pushed` and `full_name` (default). I suggest you actually read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

For GitHub, the correct property is `per_page`.

Just bear in mind that limiting results has nothing to do with Axios or any front-end tool. It is a backend implementation, and any backend developer is free to do it the way they want. Although there are some standards, such as [cursor pagination](https://jsonapi.org/profiles/ethanresnick/cursor-pagination/).

In a real project, the backend and frontend developer would have a "contract" for how this would work, so both know how the property will work.